# Alternative to TransactionScope (DTC) for .NET Core EntityFramework in a Linux Docker Container with a Windows Server Database (Multi-DB Commit Issue)

Tags: c#, docker, entity-framework-core, transactions

I am currently working on a project where my program runs in a Linux Docker container and my database is hosted on a Windows Server. The program uses .NET Core and EntityFramework to interact with the database. I have a scenario with nested transactions where I need to write data to my database, but I need to ensure that all the data is only committed if there are no errors in the process.

To achieve this, I initially tried using TransactionScope (DTC), but encountered the following error: "This platform does not support distributed transactions." This seems to be caused by the fact that my program is running on a Linux container.

Given this situation, what alternatives can I use to implement a similar transactional behavior that works with my setup? Are there any known workarounds or best practices for handling nested transactions and multi-database scenarios in a Linux Docker container with a .NET Core EntityFramework application and a Windows Server database?

As an alternative, I tried to collect all IDbContextTransaction instances using a custom Scope, and after the last Scope is disposed, I commit all transactions. However, the problem arises when I have multiple databases involved, and for example, the third commit fails due to a timeout. In this case, the previous transactions are already committed, and I need a way to roll back those changes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you figure out an option for this? I'm in the same scenario. Thanks.